# How to configure a distributed network for the replication?

Tags: routing, vpn, internet, ipsec, redistribution

I want to replicate data (music, video, photos, user's data) across different geographical networks. How to connect several networks into a single network to let nodes comunicate to each other? 
Example:
I have several nodes in the network 192.168.0.0/24 and several nodes in the network 10.0.0.0/24. Nodes have to be able to replicate data from nodes in 192.168.0.1/24 to nodes in 10.0.0.0/24 and vice versa.
I have read about VPN but I am not sure what solution I need to use and when.
I can't decide what to use OpenVPN or IPsec or another solution. Can you suggest me what to use for data replication between networks?

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here (the same is true of most SE sites), as are questions about protocols above OSI layer-4.

Comment: Also note that home networking questions are off-topic. It's not clear whether your question is about a home network or not, (discussing music, video, and photos seems like personal data, but could be business related) but just FYI. There is the [SuperUser Stack Exchange](http://superuser.com/) for home networking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to find some devices or software that are designed to establish VPN connections and read the documentation for how to set it up. Many networks use the network firewall as a VPN endpoint. You purchase and configure firewalls for each of your locations and configure VPNs between the locations.

Product recommendations are off-topic here, so you'll have to select one or more VPN products using some other resource. Once you have them, if you have questions about how to configure the VPNs, that is on-topic here.